# What characterises a rapid delay line?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, photonics

When reading into [Adaptive Sampling for Terahertz Time-Domain Spectroscopy and Imaging](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7815408), it is stated:

*"In general, the advantage of a rapid delay
line is high repetition rate, and the SNR can be improved by
increasing the number of scans."*

I understand the concept of a delay line as represented in the image below and that the delay line is the signal that, is delayed when compared to the original signal, by increasing its path length,

[image]

**but I don't understand what defines a rapid delay line. Is it a shorter period/space between the peaks of the original and the delayed signal?**

What I mean by this is, is it the spacing between the orange and red peaks represented in the image below?

It seems to be in every way similar to the step scan delay.

[image]

**And how does a rapid delay line lead to a higher repetition rate?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partly a guess, but

A rapid delay line is one that can change its delay setting rapidly.

It allows higher repetition rates because it doesn't take as long to move the delay line through the range of positions required for each scan, therefore the scan can be completed more quickly and the next scan can be begun sooner.

Comment: So almost like a computational setup that moves from position to position automatically, instead of it having to be done manually?

Comment: @user7077252, I don't know what a computational setup is. But presumably (I can't access the full PDF you linked to) this measurement requires moving the delay line to several different positions and measuring something at each of those positions. If you can move the delay line faster, then you can complete the whole measurement faster.

Comment: Hello again, I just have one question which is : What would make it move faster? That is my biggest problem, I can't picture anything, unless it was some sort of program that moved the setup.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user7077252, yes, it would be an automated or computer-controlled system. To make it faster you might need a more powerful motor, different gears, smoother bearings, motion control algorithms that start and stop it without vibrations, mechanical design that avoids resonances, etc.